# Move GridLayout rows to top

Tags: qml, row, grid-layout

I have a GridLayout and when there aren't enough items to fill the available space, the rows seem to space out evenly to fill the vertical space. But I would like the rows to be forced to the top of the GridLayout.

If I remove the lower anchor and set a Layout.maximumHeight then my container shrinks so the items appear at the top, but I'm not sure that's the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Put the GridLayout in a ColumnLayout with an Item that expands. E.g.

```
ColumnLayout {
    // anchors or Layout settings to size it.

    GridLayout {
        // Let it size itself vertically implicitly.
    }

    Item {
        // Use this to fill the space below it.
        Layout.fillHeight: true
    }
}
```